# Does it matter to which ground you connect a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, batteries, dc, charging

I'm a beginner when it comes to electrical engineering and recently started a project where I build my own portable bluetooth speakers. I already have a rough layout of the whole thing. I basically want to power a 2x50 Watt Amplifier with two batterypacks wired in parallel, that I weld together myself.

Now I also want to be able to drive it with a 100W Powersupply, but in a way where I can plug in the Powersupply and flip a switch to disconnect the batteries from the circuit, so the speakers don't draw power from them. If I were to not flip the switch, the powersupply should work as a charger, independent of if the device is on or not. Instead of using multiple switches for this I wanted to use a MOSFET to close the battery circuit whenever the powersupply is plugged in, by using the 20V it would provide. Does it matter to which groundwire I connect the gate?

I will post a "schematic" or rather sketch of the whole thing below. I am aware that what I drew might be not applicable at all. So please point out all mistakes you find, after all I came here to learn. I would also appreciate any beginner resources for learning more.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Comment: Looking at the schematic: closing the switch will connect the power supply directly to the batteries through the diode, and also short the power supply. The switch doesn't disconnect the batteries from the amplifier. There is no proper battery charger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it matters. You must make sure that the gate is controlled in reference to the source.

Edit for the OP: You need to make sure that your gate is always connected to a part of the circuit that is connected to the source in such a way as to know the potential difference between the source and the gate. In you circuit, it is unclear that this is true. So I'm not going to say you can't make it work. But if your circuit block that you have labeled +16,8V has diodes or other components that isolates the source from the rest of the circuit when there is no power from the 20V supply, then any voltage you apply to the MOSFET is not going to turn it on (which should be fine since this is the desired state). But when you plug in your 20V power supply, the MOSFET will still be off so you won't charge the batteries. then when you turn on your switch with the 20V power supply attached, you're going to short that power supply. Maybe if you move the line from 20V- to the other side of the resistor, you might get a little closer without any smoke but your MOSFET is still off because it's tied to something that is negative relative to the source (off for an N-Channel MOSFET). Also, you probably don't want the MOSFET in the 20V power line, you want it to disconnect the Batteries when the 20V is plugged in.

Edit for everyone else: Let's just replace the imaginary circuit with one that is more likely to work with battery management and system power selection with well documented operation. Not quite the same learning experience though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8NhLB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just to be clear... A MOSFET functions by the application of an electric field between the source and gate. You must apply your control voltage at those two pins or it will not work. How is that not the answer to the original question that was asked.

Comment: Can you expand\edit your answer and make it more comprehensive?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser Thanks for the explanations. I dont want to take up too much of your time, but the circuit you designed doesn't have any Voltage stepdown regulator. Wouldnt that be needed if I charged battery packs with a maximum of 16,8 Volts, or can I Charge with higher voltage as long as im using a proper BMS that has the necessary protections? Also are the Dioides 1 and 2 there to protect the BMSs if there is a voltage difference between the two?

Comment: @T.M If you are learning something then it's not a waste of time and I'm happy to be able to help. One of the glorious things about the BQ24753A and similar charge controllers is that they act as a buck/boost converter for charging the batteries independently of being a buck/boost converter for your load, and they switch between input sources and batteries automatically. Okay, you do have to build a complicated circuit, but you don't have to design it. Once you have more design experience, then you can design your own circuits because you see a gap in the circuits that are already available.

Comment: @T.M I don't want to spoil your learning experience by removing trial and error. On one hand, a good engineer does not waste time designing circuits that they can easily buy. On the other, sometimes you need to breadboard a circuit to better understand how it works. In this case, I'd say that it would be useful to breadboard some MOSFET circuits for power switching but maybe not for inclusion in the final product.